# Can we find all roots by using the inverse quadratic interpolation?

Tags: roots, interpolation, inverse-function, lagrange-interpolation

Can we find all the real roots of a function by using the inverse quadratic interpolation? How can we do that?

Can we find complex roots?

How can we find any root of a function having roots we have no guess about by using that algorithm, how should we start?

Comment: @Moo I found one root of a quartic equation by using this method and it had 2 double roots. I knew the roots so I actually determined the values of three xs near to one of the roots and found that root. I know that I can find the other one like this but what if I have no idea about its roots? How should I start in such kind of a case?

Comment: @Moo and yes, I am also asking for an example of the thing I mentioned on the comment before and an example for finding complex roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inverse Quadratic Interpolation (IQI) is described on the [*Wiki*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_quadratic_interpolation) and in [*Section 4.5*](https://math.boisestate.edu/~wright/courses/m365/zeros.pdf). Note some of the pitfalls mentioned there.

Both of the references give the iteration formula. This method can be used to find all roots of a polynomial, whether they are real or complex.

As an example, take $f(x) = 4 x^3-16 x^2+17 x-4$. I usually start by plotting the function to get an idea of where the roots are for each of the three initial points needed to find each one. The plot is [image]

I will also use a professional package like Matlab or Mathematica to find the roots to high precision for comparison purposes (you can also find exact roots using the [*Cubic Equation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation)). The three real numerical roots are

$ x = 0.32853845861141489597 \\ x = 1.2646582900644196963 \\ x = 2.4068032513241654077$

Using IQI, for the first root, try $x_0 = 2, x_1 = 1, x_2 = 0$ (look at how many iterations it took to converge and compare to Newton-Raphson or Brent's Method)

- $x_0  =  2.0000000000000000$
- $x_1  =  1.0000000000000000$
- $x_2  =  0.0000000000000000$
- $x_3  =  1.8666666666666670$
- $x_4  =  1.7779534353544020$
- $x_5  = -2.3569618956708820$
- $x_6  =  0.4784180205707038$
- $x_7  =  0.9077436276533210$
- $x_8  = -0.6942151494047211$
- $x_9  = -0.6478506170435796$
- $x_{10}  =  0.7821913121990205$
- $x_{11}  =  0.6535526131045359$
- $x_{12}  = -5.0833208694930590$
- $x_{13}  = -5.4278849866262590$
- $x_{14}  =  0.6414926269507966$
- $x_{15}  =  0.6295990778705232$
- $x_{16}  = -0.2696592988054403$
- $x_{17}  = -0.1734466885955047$
- $x_{18}  =  0.4598565766321493$
- $x_{19}  =  0.3761056340942091$
- $x_{20}  =  0.3197243223248978$
- $x_{21}  =  0.3282034018254270$
- $x_{22}  =  0.3285391069447241$
- $x_{23}  =  0.3285384586194860$
- $x_{24}  =  0.3285384586114148$
- $x_{25}  =  0.3285384586114150$
- $x_{26}  =  0.3285384586114149$
- $x_{27}  =  0.3285384586114150$

Using IQI, for the second root, try $x_0 = .4, x_1 = .6, x_2 = .8$

- $x_0 =  0.4000000000000000$
- $x_1 =  0.6000000000000000$
- $x_2 =  0.8000000000000000$
- $x_3 =  1.4655175639021420$
- $x_4 = -0.0269635090089693$
- $x_5 =  1.3587749241884970$
- $x_6 =  1.2072677833794600$
- $x_7 =  1.2757986938031020$
- $x_8 =  1.2645991028116670$
- $x_9 =  1.2646583297719020$
- $x_{10} =  1.2646582900643940$
- $x_{11} =  1.2646582900644190$

Using IQI, for the first root, try $x_0 = .4, x_1 = .6, x_2 = .8$

- $x_0 =  3.0000000000000000$
- $x_1 =  2.8000000000000000$
- $x_2 =  2.6000000000000000$
- $x_3 =  2.4456842900259870$
- $x_4 =  2.4111121815239560$
- $x_5 =  2.4068782724818820$
- $x_6 =  2.4068032896187870$
- $x_7 =  2.4068032513242060$
- $x_8 =  2.4068032513241660$

For a complex example, lets use $f(x) = x^2 + 1$, which has the imaginary roots $x = \pm ~ i$.

Using IQI, for the first root, try $x_0 = .5 + I,  x_1 = .6 + I, x_2 = .7 + I$ ($I$ is imaginary)

- $x_0 =  0.5000000000000000+ 1.0000000000000000 I$
- $x_1 =  0.6000000000000000+ 1.0000000000000000 I$
- $x_2 =  0.7000000000000000+ 1.0000000000000000 I$
- $x_3 = -0.0265008880606977+ 0.9324794583256370 I$
- $x_4 = -0.0062809706136977+ 1.0111496938882190 I$
- $x_5 = -0.0002495550153420+ 0.9998210667715290 I$
- $x_6 =  1.1033465890063210 \times 10^{-7}+ 1.0000000998346370 I$
- $x_7 = -2.7745525061489970 \times 10^{-13}+ 0.9999999999999160 I$
- $x_8 =  5.2939559203393770 \times 10^{-23}+ 1.0000000000000000 I$
- $x_9 =  0.0000000000000000+ 1.0000000000000000 I$

Using IQI, for the second root, try $x_0 = .5 - I,  x_1 = .6 - I, x_2 = .7 - I$ ($I$ is imaginary)

$ x_ 0 =  0.5000000000000000- 1.0000000000000000 I$
$ x_ 1 =  0.6000000000000000- 1.0000000000000000 I$
$ x_ 2 =  0.7000000000000000- 1.0000000000000000 I$
$ x_ 3 = -0.0265008880606977- 0.9324794583256370 I$
$ x_ 4 = -0.0062809706136977- 1.0111496938882190 I$
$ x_ 5 = -0.0002495550153420- 0.9998210667715290 I$
$ x_ 6 =  1.1033465890063210 \times 10^{-7}- 1.0000000998346370 I$
$ x_ 7 = -2.7745525061489970 \times 10^{-13}- 0.9999999999999160 I$
$ x_ 8 =  5.2939559203393770 \times 10^{-23}- 1.0000000000000000 I$
$ x_ 9 =  0.0000000000000000- 1.0000000000000000 I$

Your last question is not easy to answer because there are pros and cons to any numerical algorithm. Sometimes, it ends up being trial and error due to the problem itself. You might be interested in reviewing the various [*methods*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) of root finding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At the end of your answer, you stated that it is not easy to answer, but don't we have any method to guess whereabouts of the root(s)? I don't really know about it for now but I remember like I read something about Bisection method that may help us with guessing the place where root(s) may be. Can you explain more about? Thanks again.

Comment: Even for Bisection, you have to know a range where a root actually exists. You could plot it to find general location. For most algorithms, you can test function values until you find a range where there is a positive and negative function result and that is your range. It still does not guarantee that the algorithm will find it. With some algorithms, like Newton's, the guess just has to be close enough and it will likely converge.

Comment: thanks again. I would also like to ask how the approximation of coefficient of the imaginary part is determined? I mean, even if you see the graph, how can you guess the value of non-visible roots? For example what can the roots be of this graph? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/icg8v5ugq7

Comment: I would do something like this - see the real vs imaginary plots. This has fourteen (7 pairs) of imaginary roots. Using [*Wolfram Alpha*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*x%5E14+%2B+3*x+%2B+5). Notice that all of the imaginary roots have a real and imaginary part, so there are no crossovers. Wolfram shows you all of the 14 roots. You can use that as a starting point for things like Newton's Method, but it won't be easy.

Comment: Is it not possible to have any idea about the complex roots from the graph of the function?

Comment: Sometimes tools like Wolfram Alpha can provide a visualization and sometimes not. Your $x^{14}$  was an example of where it is not useful. These are typically hard to find initial conditions for so you guess.